# Automatic table layout and colspan

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I'm creating an app which allows the user to manipulate a table structure by adding and removing columns and rows, setting column widths and cell colspans, and inserting elements into table cells. While testing, I came across a scenario in which Firefox 4 and Internet Explorer 8 render the table in the way I expect it to be rendered and Google Chrome 11 doesn't. I'm using table-layout: auto and I am aware that CSS does not specify a rendering algorithm to be used in this case (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/tables.html, section 17.5.2.2). Nonetheless, I'd like to have consistent views in the three mentioned browsers, if possible.

Here's a very simple scenario to illustrate the different rendering (try it in Chrome and Firefox/IE to see the difference): http://jsbin.com/ayuja4/3

Even though the table is wide enough to contain the blue div (because the first column is set to 200 px and the second column, although having a width of 100 px, must expand to 300 px to contain the green div), in Chrome the first column is widened beyond its 200 px. This results in extra, unnecessary space in the last row, which is precisely what I'm trying to avoid.

Any ideas to make this table look the same in Chrome as it does in Firefox and Internet Explorer? I don't need a pure HTML/CSS approach - manipulating the table with JavaScript is a valid option, if it solves my problem. I'm already considering using fixed table layout, but this will result in extra effort to handle elements that are wider than columns, so it's a last resort.

Comment: Seems to be a bug in Chrome, even IE 6 gets it right. Report the bug, hoepfully they'll fix it, Chrome users will get an autoupdate (impossible to avoid unless you don't connect to the internet) and your work is done.

Comment: I've reported it through Chrome's bug report feature. Unfortunately, this means I won't receive any feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make the divs inside the table display as cells with `table div {display:table-cell;}` you'll get the same results. Also, the way you're going about it now is leaving a 1px gap because the 500px element doesn't get the 1px border calculated into it.

I actually took a second look at it, and if you use `min-width` instead of `width` it'll work that way too.

Comment: If I apply "display:table-cell" to all divs in the table, the first column expands beyond its intended 200 px and the second column's width becomes less than 300 px, and so the intented width of the green div (300 px) is not respected (demo: http://jsbin.com/ayuja4/5). This happens in Chrome and Internet Explorer. In Firefox the columns are 200 and 100 px wide, and so neither div has its width respected.

Comment: If I apply min-width instead of width, Chrome still doesn't get it right and Firefox and Internet Explorer render the table exactly as if I had used width instead of min-width (demo: http://jsbin.com/ayuja4/6). But if I apply "display:table-cell" only to the blue div, all three browser render the table as I expect (demo: http://jsbin.com/ayuja4/7), so it's a satisfying solution. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Sorry, I was unclear. I meant if you apply `min-width` to the `<th>`s you have that should fix it too ([http://jsfiddle.net/MKGwe/](http://jsfiddle.net/MKGwe/)). Glad one of them worked despite my poor explanation, haha!

Comment: Indeed, this also works, and it actually is a better solution for my real scenario. Thanks again!